# Use bookmark value in WORD for sql query

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, ms-word

I am currently trying to build an automated WORD business letter that fills out corresponding data such as company address, company name, today's date, deadline date and so on after I have typed in a 5 digit number.

The number and all other fields are bookmarks.

Whenever the user types in a specific 5 digit number into the bookmark named "theNumber", this value will be used for an SQL query (Oracle). **The query then fills out all other bookmarks!**

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 Function dbQuery(ByVal TM As String, ByVal myNumber As String) As Boolean

        Dim sqlrumpf As String
        Dim sqlstring As String
        Dim connstring As String

         With ActiveDocument
           If .Bookmarks.Exists(TM) Then
            Dim TMRange As Range
              Set TMRange = .Bookmarks(TM).Range
               TMRange = myNumber
              .Bookmarks.Add TM, TMRange
              dbQuery = True
            Else
                Debug.Print "Bookmark not found: " & TM
           End If
        End With

        sqlrumpf = "SELECT p.name " & _
        "FROM xy.person p, xy.adresse a, wz.zusatz1 z, xy.vorgang v " & _
        "WHERE p.adresse_id = a.adresse_id " & _
        "AND z.aktnr = v.vorgang_id " & _
        "AND a.adresse_id = v.adresse_id " & _
        "AND v.vorgang_nr = '"

        sqlstring = sqlrumpf & myNumber & "'"
        connstring = "ODBC;DSN=mydsn;UID=myuid;DBQ=my.dbq.lan;DBA=W;APA=T;PFC=1;TLO=0;PWD=mypw;"

        QueryTables.Add _
        (Connection:=connstring, _
        Destination:=Range(TMRange), _
        Sql:=sqlstring).Refresh

End Function
Sub Main()

    If dbQuery("theNumber", "12345") = False Then
      MsgBox "Database query failed!"
   End If

End Sub
```

I get the error:

> Runtime Error '4608': Value not within definition range.

How can I fix this?

The error seems to occur here:

```
Destination:=Range(TMRange), _
```

Normally I use this query only for excel when I want to print a query into a single cell.

Is it generally a bad idea to use bookmarks with sql queries in this manner?
Which fields would you use if not bookmarks? 
How do you query bookmark values?

Comment: Word does not have `QueryTables` - that's purely an Excel functionality. You might investigate using a Word `Database` field. This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116302/using-vba-to-automate-a-microsoft-word-document-with-data-imported-from-an-excel/35117471#35117471